# Trying to rewrite SQL in Lambda-LinQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, lambda

I'm migrating some SQL scripts into Lambda, but I cannot figure out yet how to translate this SQL

```
SELECT
    COUNT([ProcessID]) AS [Count],
    [ProcessType],
    AVG(DATEDIFF(s, [StartDate], [EndDate])) AS [AverageDuration]
FROM
    [ProcessTable]
WHERE
    [InstanceID] = @InstanceID
    AND [ProcessType] = @ProcessType
    AND [ProcessStatus] = 3 -- Finished
GROUP BY
    [ProcessType]
```

EDIT: I tried the following, but it don't fully understand how Average works

```
var result = (from p in ctx.ProcessTable
              where p.ProcessInstanceID.Equals(processInstanceID)
                 && p.ProcessType.Equals(processType)
                 && p.ProcesoStatusEquals(ProcessStatusEnum.FINISHED)
              group p by p.ProcessType into tp
              select new 
              {
                  Count = tp.Count(tp.ProcessID),
                  AverageDuration = tp.Average(p => p.EndDate - p.StarDate)
                  ProcesType = tp.ProcesType
              });
```

Any help will be appreciated.. Thanks in advance

Comment: Edited with my latest Attempt...

Comment: Why don't you implement the raw query into a repository instead of using Entity Framework?

Comment: It is a requirement. For some reason they don't want any Sql in the project and only EF. The original query is inside an Stored Procedure that worked fine in the previous version of the project.

Comment: Try : p.EndDate.Date - p.StarDate.Date.  The SQL script is using whole days while you conversion is using parts of a day.

Comment: Thanks @jdweng but I finally used TotalSeconds in the diff. See reply below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tries i figured out. I answer myself in case anyone is interested...

```
class ProcessResult
{
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public double AverageDuration { get; set; }
    public string ProcessType { get; set; }
}

var result = (from p in ctx.ProcessTable
              where p.ProcessInstanceID.Equals(processInstanceID)
                 && p.ProcessType.Equals(processType)
                 && p.ProcesoStatusEquals(ProcessStatusEnum.FINISHED)
              group p by p.ProcessType into tp
              select new ProcessResult
              {
                  Count = tp.Count(),
                  AverageDuration = tp.Average(p => DbFunctions.DiffSeconds(p.StartDate, p.EndDate)),
                  ProcessType = tp.Key
              }).SingleOrDefault();
```